# JMapViewer centering

Tags: java, swing, jmapviewer

I am trying to put a JMapViewer into a program I am doing and I want it to be centered in a specific area (Leicester, UK). Although I am not sure how the .setDisplayPosition function works and how I can use the co ordinates i have for it to do this task? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JMapViewer#setDisplayPositionByLatLon()` to zoom to a particular point.

Addendum: *I don't have the method* `setDisplayPositionByLatLon()`.

Ah, the method was removed in `r30244` in favor of `setDisplayPosition()`.

```
Coordinate paris = new Coordinate(48.8567, 2.3508);
map.setDisplayPosition(paris, 8);
```

From the log:

```
$ svn log -r30244 src/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/JMapViewer.java 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r30244 | glebius | 2014-01-31 07:51:51 -0500 (Fri, 31 Jan 2014) | 3 lines

To match getPosition() and simplify code rename setDisplayPositionByLatLon()
into setDisplayPosition(Coordinate to, ...).
```

Comment: I don't have the method 'setDisplayPositionByLatLon' for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I had an older revision; more above.

Comment: @ trashgod: I am having some troubles with raster data in JMapViewer. May I kindly ask for your assistence. Thank you very much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955859/jmapviewer-load-raster-to-a-position